# httpcontext.current.server.mappath Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception

I am using the following code within a class:

```
string filePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/email/teste.html");
```

The file teste.html is in the folder

But when it will open the file the following error is being generated:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Is the call to `MapPath` where the exception is occurring?  It sounds like maybe there is a different line that throws the exception, if that's the case, can you post the line that actually throws the exception.

Comment: Almost all cases of `NullReferenceException` are the same. Please see "[What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)" for some hints.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Don't use Server.MapPath. It's slow. Use this instead, `HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath`. As long as your web site is running, this property is always available to you.

Then use it like this:

```
string filePath = Path.Combine(HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath, "email/teste.html");
```

Comment: Getting error: "Non-invocable member 'System.Web.HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath' cannot be used like a method." while using in class library.

Comment: Jitendra, HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath is a property, not a method. Regards, Nick

Comment: oh!! its really great worked finally after a longtime

Comment: @user12345, glad it helped you out.

Comment: will this work when i deploy my code in server? @nickytonline

Comment: @thiru, yes it will.

Comment: This also will not work with relative paths such as `../images/`

Comment: So i actually need to do the same thing...but from within a Unit Test. Can you please suggest something!

Answer (score 8):

if the code is not running from within a thread is executing a `httprequest` then `HttpContext.Current` is `null` (for example when you method is called via `BeginInvoke`) - see http://forums.asp.net/t/1131004.aspx/1 .

You can always use `HttpRuntime` see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpruntime.aspx

Answer (score 7):

If there is no `HttpContext` (e.g. when the method is called via `BeginInvoke`, as Yahia pointed out), the call to `HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath()` must fail. For those scenarios, there's `HostingEnvironment.MapPath()` in the `System.Web.Hosting` namespace.

```
string filePath = HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/email/teste.html");
```

Comment: This does not handle relative paths such as `../images/`

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like the following piece of code. One thing to note is that I was facing an issue, where I was trying to access a .txt file from within a TestMethod and everything was failing except for this...and yeah it works for non-Unit Test Scenarios too.

`string filePath = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory,@"..\..") + "\\email\\teste.html";`

Answer (score 0):

Issue: I had an "Images" folder inside a class library project. But using the above answers, I was not able to get the physical path of the folder to read/write the files inside that folder.

Solution: The below code worked for me to get a physical path in the class library project.

```
string physicalPath = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath("..\\..\\Images");
```

I hope, it will help someone who is facing the same issue as me.