# HttpContext.Current null inside FileSystemWatcher

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, filesystemwatcher, httpcontext

I have an ASP.NET MVC 4 applicaton.

Also I have a XML file located on the root of my application.

Whenever administrator changes this file, I want the applicaton know about it and read the new values.

```
...
FileSystemWatcher Watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
Watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
...

private void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e) {
    var path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/"))
}
```

Every time `HttpContext.Current` seems to be null. How to get the root folder of my application, if this does not work?

Answer (score 0):

> How to get the root folder of my application, if this does not work?

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
```

Answer (score 0):

just what you need,

```
var domainPath = HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath;
```

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6861368/httpcontext-current-server-mappath-object-
reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6861368/httpcontext-current-server-mappath-object-%20reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an)

Answer (score 0):

And yet another alternative; [HostingEnvironment.MapPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.hostingenvironment.mappath%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). What `Server.MapPath` does, without an active HttpContext.

See [What is the difference between Server.MapPath and HostingEnvironment.MapPath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/944219/what-is-the-difference-between-server-mappath-and-hostingenvironment-mappath)

> in reality, the only difference is that you are allowed to pass null to Server.MapPath(), but not to HostingEnvironment.MapPath()