# Server.MapPath for a custom class?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to use

```
Server.MapPath
```

In my file location, which has worked perfectly so far in my project, however now I have ceated a new class inside the App_Code folder in my site and I can no longer use "Server" ,I get the error

"Error  4 The name 'Server' does not exist in the current context"

How can I fix this? I would like to be able to use Server.MapPath instead of alternatives as I have already done this for the rest of the site, so is there anyway? If not what are my alternatives?

I also tried

```
~\\App_Code\\myfile
```

But this didn't work either. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Just use the full namespace:

```
HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(...);
```

Comment: Alternatively... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6861368/httpcontext-current-server-mappath-object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an

Comment: Thanks a lot mate! Ill vote this as best answer in 3 minutes when I'm allowed