# HttpContext.Current.Server threw an exception of type System.NullReferenceException when I deploy to my server

Tags: .net, exception, deployment, httpcontext

For some reason after deploying the same code that works perfectly on localhost to my server this line fails:

```
private static string nodePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["NodeJS.Path"]);
```

The original exception is `System.TypeInitializationException`: The type initializer for 'Turcos.App.Components.AsyncFileExporter' threw an exception. But it's clear to see that the exception is thrown because `HttpContext.Current` is null.

I understand that `HttpContext.Current` can be null sometimes (https://stackoverflow.com/a/6861575/1519464) but why it's working on my local and not on the server? What's even more weird is that the code that I prevously had on my server was using `HttpContext.Current` and it worked perfectly. What could have changed that stoped this from working?

Comment: what type of host is deployed server?

Comment: Windows Server 2012 running on an AWS instance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I finally found the cause.
After deploying, my class in question was being called via a .net API controller, so it seems that the when `HttpContext.Current` was trying to be used in this line: 
`private static string nodePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["NodeJS.Path"]);`, it wasn't initialized so it threw the exception.

The solution: after the deployment, the first thing I did was loading index.html and it seems that it triggered a proper initialization of all static attributes as the issue stopped happening.
At the end of the day, it was a tricky initialization/ lifecycle issue